# Congressional Bills into R data table

Tags: xml, r

I've read many articles, some from stackoverflow, with examples on how to extract data from xml files into a data table in R. However I have been unsuccessful in my attempts, perhaps it's because of my xml files? Im posting an example xml file, if someone could give it a look over and point me in a direction to get these files I have into a table, it would be most helpful.

```
 ' <bill session="113" type="s" number="12" updated="2014-09-20T07:17:52-04:00">
  <state datetime="2013-02-26">REFERRED</state>
  <status>
    <introduced datetime="2013-02-26"/>
  </status>
  <introduced datetime="2013-02-26"/>
  <titles>
    <title type="short" as="introduced">Naval Vessel Transfer Act of 2013</title>
    <title type="official" as="introduced">A bill to provide for the transfer of naval vessels to      certain foreign recipients.</title>
  </titles>
  <sponsor id="402675"/>
  <cosponsors>
    <cosponsor id="412491" joined="2013-11-05"/>
  </cosponsors>
  <actions>
    <action datetime="2013-02-26" state="REFERRED">
      <text>Read twice and referred to the Committee on Foreign Relations.</text>
    </action>
  </actions>
  <committees>
    <committee code="SSFR" name="Senate Foreign Relations" activity="Referral, In Committee"/>
  </committees>
  <relatedbills>
    <bill relation="unknown" session="113" type="s" number="1683"/>
  </relatedbills>
  <subjects>
    <term name="International affairs"/>
    <term name="Asia"/>
    <term name="Buy American requirements"/>
    <term name="Latin America"/>
    <term name="Marine and inland water transportation"/>
    <term name="Mexico"/>
    <term name="Military assistance, sales, and agreements"/>
    <term name="Military facilities and property"/>
    <term name="Taiwan"/>
    <term name="Thailand"/>
  </subjects>
  <amendments/>
  <summary>2/26/2013--Introduced.
 Naval Vessels Transfer Act of 2013 - Authorizes the President to transfer on a grant basis to: (1)         Mexico, the OLIVER HAZARD PERRY class guided missile frigates CURTS and MCCLUSKY; and (2) Thailand, the         OLIVER HAZARD PERRY class guided missile frigates RENTZ and VANDEGRIFT.

Authorizes the President to transfer on a sale basis the OLIVER HAZARD PERRY class guided missile     frigates TAYLOR, GARY, CARR, and ELROD to the Taipei Economic and Cultural Representative Office of the     United States (which is the Taiwan instrumentality designated pursuant to the Taiwan Relations Act).

States that: (1) the value of such vessels transferred on a grant basis shall not be counted against  the aggregate value of excess defense articles transferred to countries in any fiscal year under the  Foreign Assistance Act of 1961; (2) transfer costs shall be charged to the recipient; and (3) to the  maximum extent practicable, the country to which a vessel is transferred shall have necessary vessel  repair and refurbishment carried out at U.S. shipyards (including U.S. Navy shipyards).

Terminates transfer authority three years after enactment of this Act.</summary>
</bill> '
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please include your attempts in your question. [I recommend you read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you want the imported "table" to look like? The example file clearly looks to have nested relationships what will not translate well to a rectangular data format required by data tables.

Comment: Oh I see, Ive just been tasked to get these files into a data frame. So because they're nested they wont be taken nicely?

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting the XML into separate bills (avoiding related bills) and then use xpath queries to select whatever columns you need using lapply or a loop.

```
doc <- xmlParse("lotsofbills.xml")
nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//bill[not(ancestor::bill)]")

 x <- lapply(nodes, function(x){ data.frame(
   bill_session = xpathSApply(x, ".", xmlGetAttr, "session"),
    short_title = xpathSApply(x, ".//title[@type='short']", xmlValue),
action_datetime = xpathSApply(x, ".//actions/action", xmlGetAttr, "datetime"),
         action = xpathSApply(x, ".//actions/action/text", xmlValue),
       subjects = paste( xpathSApply(x, ".//subjects/term", xmlGetAttr, "name"), collapse="; ")
)})

do.call("rbind", x)
  bill_session                       short_title action_datetime                                                         action
1          113 Naval Vessel Transfer Act of 2013      2013-02-26 Read twice and referred to the Committee on Foreign Relations.
                                                                                                                                                                                                               subjects
1 International affairs; Asia; Buy American requirements; Latin America; Marine and inland water transportation; Mexico; Military assistance, sales, and agreements; Military facilities and property; Taiwan; Thailand
```

And for comparison, here's a loop, which may be easier to use if you are unfamiliar with the xml file

```
x<-vector("list", length(nodes))

for (i in 1:length(nodes)){
subDoc <- xmlDoc(nodes[[i]])
   bill_session <- xpathSApply(subDoc, "/bill", xmlGetAttr, "session")
    short_title <- xpathSApply(subDoc, "//title[@type='short']", xmlValue)
action_datetime <- xpathSApply(subDoc, "//actions/action", xmlGetAttr, "datetime")
         action <- xpathSApply(subDoc, "//actions/action/text", xmlValue)
       subjects <- paste( xpathSApply(subDoc, "//subjects/term", xmlGetAttr, "name"), collapse="; ")
 x[[i]] <- data.frame(bill_session, short_title, action_datetime, action, subjects)
free(subDoc)
}
```

Comment: Was also thinking that the "subjects" could be flattened into a single string with ","'s unless they individual classifications are needed separately, then setup a slew of logical columns. `rbindlist` from `data.table` can munge them all together nicely.